# How to change text color in TextWrangler on Mac

Tags: macos, editor, text-editor, textwrangler

I cannot figure out how to do this.

All I want to do is to select some text and then change the color of that text to red, say. I've lost 20 minutes of my life trying to do this.

Typing 'font color' into help search brings up a reference to lesson 2, which doesn't even contain the word font or color. (Is TextWrangler low quality?)

How do I do this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TextWrangler is a text editor, not a word processor. You can pick any font or color you like the display the text for a given file, but you can't format different parts of the same file differently - it's just plain text after all.

Comment: Well, it does syntax highlighting, so you can have different text being different colours - but that is down to the pattern matching on syntax rules, not to arbitrary text.

Comment: @David Dorward: True, but that's just a cosmetic feature of the display logic - underneath it's still just a plain unformatted text file.

Comment: I know this is a very old thread, but, can someone tell me how I can change the font color for the entire text? I have been trying to do it with no luck. It is very frustrating! Thanks.

Comment: @dml: try posting a new question perhaps ? [su] might be a more appropriate place for it though.

Comment: @Paul R. Thanks! I just did. http://superuser.com/questions/1088338/textwrangler-mac-how-to-change-the-font-color-for-the-entire-text

Comment: @PaulR, Not apple.se?

Comment: @Pacerier: yes, my bad - http://apple.stackexchange.com would be the best place to ask. (The original question was from 2010!)